# Angular Firebase MatTable 2 observables in 1

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a data structure on my Firebase DB that has a reference to a user id.

I'm trying to "put the object together" but I'm having issues. Here is an example:

Original data on my collection:

```
{
city: new york,
country: usa
addedBy: feibf78UYV3e43 // This is the USER ID from the User Collection.
}
```

What I need to do is to fetch the user information for each document on my collection, however, I'm getting the user data as Observable, how can I do that?
The object should look like:

```
{
city: new york,
country: usa
addedBy: feibf78UYV3e43 // This is the USER ID from the User Collection.
addedByProfile: {
    firstName: John,
    lastName: Doe,
    age: 34
  }
}
```

I tried creating 2 subscriptions but it didn't work.

Here is my basic code without the secondary query.

```
getAllIncome() {
        return this.incomeService.getAllIncomeShops().subscribe(
            snaps => {
                const incomeShops = snaps.map(snap => {
                    // I had the call to my UserService here on which I called the getUser() method passing the UID, however, I need to subscribe for that and it messes things up.
                    return {
                        id: snap.payload.doc.id,
                        ...snap.payload.doc.data()
                    } as IncomeShop;
                });
                this.showLoader = false;
                this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(incomeShops);
                this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
                this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
            }
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
dataWithUser =[];
this.incomeService.getAllIncomeShops()
 .pipe(
      mergeMap(datas => {
        return datas.map(data => {
          return zip(of(data), this.userService.getUser(data.addedBy));
        });
      }),
      mergeAll()
    )
    .subscribe(([data, user]) => {
      dataWithUser = [...dataWithUser, { ...data, addedByProfile: user }];
    });
```

One problem is that the Observable emits each items of the array one at a time. So we will have to collect all of them into an array like we are doing here:

```js
dataWithUser = [...dataWithUser, { ...data, addedByProfile: user }];
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks.. quick question... my tslint is saying that ZIP is deprecated, is there another function that I can sub with?

Comment: You can use forkJoin()